# Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.0 from/to remote-repos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

When I try to build my first spring application, I'm followed by this error:

> Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.0 from/to remote-repos (https://artifactory.io.thehut.local:443/artifactory/remote-repos): Transfer failed for https://artifactory.io.thehut.local:443/artifactory/remote-repos/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.0/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.0.pom

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hello-world</name>
    <description>hello-world</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: That will not work because spring boot 3.1.0 does not yet exists... only 3.1.0-M1 existing....

Comment: what is a previous version i can use?

Comment: Hi! Current release version is 3.0.4 , and the recommended way to create your spring project/skeleton: https://start.spring.io ;)

Comment: I tried to create it this way initially but i get an error when generating the application -> "Could not connect to server. Please check your connection".
I also tried with that version (3.0.4) but i get the same error.

Comment: Ok, then error message can be explained this way: 1. (You are behind a proxy,) All maven traffic is routed to your (local) artifactory. (isolated from maven-central) 2. spring-boot (of these versions) is not available in your artifactory. Solution: Check available versions, chat with your artifactory admin.

Comment: Any way I can get off this proxy or redirect the traffic to maven central? where can I locate this?

Comment: It depends... on where your computer "stands" :) in a company: you must see/talk/find out ...probably not; at home/in public: surely, no problem!